# getting data in and out of hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I need a system to analyze large log files.  A friend directed me to hadoop the other day and it seems perfect for my needs. My question revolves around getting data into hadoop-

Is it possible to have the nodes on my cluster stream data as they get it into HDFS?  Or would each node need to write to a local temp file and submit the temp file after it reaches a certain size?  and is it possible to append to a file in HDFS while also running queries/jobs on that same file at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

[Fluentd](http://fluentd.org/) log collector just released its [WebHDFS plugin](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/out_webhdfs), which allows the users to instantly stream data into HDFS. It's really easy to install with ease of management.

[image]

- [Fluentd + Hadoop: Instant Big Data Collection](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/http-to-hdfs)

Of course you can import data directly from your applications. Here's a Java example to post logs against Fluentd.

- [Fluentd: Data Import from Java Applications](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/java)

Answer (score 1):

A hadoop job can run over multiple input files, so there's really no need to keep all your data as one file. You won't be able to process a file until its file handle is properly closed, however.

Answer (score 0):

HDFS does not support appends (yet?)

What I do is run the map-reduce job periodically and output results to an 'processed_logs_#{timestamp}" folder.
Another job can later take these processed logs and push them to a database etc. so it can be queried on-line

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Flume](http://github.com/cloudera/flume) to collect the log files from your servers into HDFS.